# How to separate "m014" using separate() function

Tags: r

I tried to separate "new_sp_m014" into four columns (new, var, sex, age). I used the following chunk :

```
task2 %>% separate(code, into = c("new","var","sex","age"), sep = "_")
```

and the result is fine for new=“new”, var=“sp”, but sex=“m014” and age is NA.

So how could I separate "m014" to sex=“m” and age=“014” as well?

Comment: We do not know what your data looks like. please type `head(new_sp_m014)` and paste the result into your question.  You might also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: OP is being literal. They're trying to split a string of the form "new_sp_m014"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two approaches:

**1) expand regex** Assuming that age is always the last 3 characters, use the regular expression shown below. It matches | or the last three characters but without consuming them.  See `?regex` for info on *zero-width positive lookahead assertions*.  The `convert=TRUE` argument is optional but if used will convert the age to numeric.

```
library(tidyr)

task2 %>% 
  separate(code, into = c("new", "var", "sex", "age"), sep = "_|(?=...$)", 
    convert = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
  new var sex age
1 new  sp   m  14
```

**2) insert _**  We can insert a _ before the age and then process it with the code in the question (except we have added the optional `convert=TRUE` as explained above) giving the same result.  We can use the default `sep` in this case or use `sep = "_"`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

task2 %>%
  mutate(code = sub("(...)$", "_\\1", code)) %>%
  separate(code, into = c("new", "var", "sex", "age"), convert = TRUE)
```

### Note

The input used, in reproducible form is:

```
task2 <- data.frame(code = "new_sp_m014")
```

Answer (score 3):

`separate()` can take an integer position at which to separate ... you can do this in two stages.

```
dd <- tibble(v="new_sp_m014")
dd %>%
    separate(v,into=c("a","b","tmp"),"_") %>%
    separate(tmp,into=c("c","d"),sep=1)
```